# Is it posible in Django to authenticate a user with 2 fields?

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication

I'm developing (currently designing) a Django app for managing students in an institute. The custom users in my app have a file number as username field. But, the app is intendeed to handle more than one institute, so i cannot use only the file number for authentication, because two students from different institutes can have the same file number. Is it posible to authenticate an user using two fields? Any clue on that?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend

Answer (score 1):

I think at the root all you have to do is create your own authentiaction backened, and register it.

```
class YourBackend(object)
  def authenticate(self, username=None, your_other_field=None):
    # get user based on username AND other field
    return user instance or None
```

Then all you have to do is register in `AUTHENTICATION_BACKEND`.  Remember:

> The order of AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS matters, so if the same username
>   and password is valid in multiple backends, Django will stop
>   processing at the first positive match.

Comment: I thougth in a custom auth backend, but i wasn't too much oriented. I guess i have to left my backend as the only item in AUTHENTUCATION_BACKENDS. So, i have to pass `username` and `the_other_field` to the function `authenticate` in `django.contrib.auth`. right? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: This is not working. I need to know how to get rid of USERNAME_FIELD in CustomUser. The field have to be unique.